# chef: only_if when a pattern exists in a file

Tags: chef-infra

I need to run a `sed` command when 2 conditions are met-

1. a file exists (eg `MYFILE.txt`)
2. file contains one particular line (e.g.  `/home/user/tools/`)

I know I can use `only_if` guard in chef, but I don't know how to mention second condition in the bash command.

Sample code:

```rb
bash 'changing path' do
  code <<-EOH
    cd /path
    sed -i -e "s:/home/user/tools/:/NEWPATH:" MYFILE.txt
  EOH
  only_if { ::File.exist?(MYFILE.txt && <<WHAT SHOULD COME HERE FOR (2)>> }
end
```

Comment: Just grep the value in the file?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `line` cookbook, it has helpers for this kind of thing which are automatically convergent.